# Reactjs: Call a function from a button that is in a string?

Tags: reactjs, string, function, onclick

I have a React project where I want to call a function from a rendered div that is inside an object. I have managed to make it call an alert function but I am unable to make it call a custom function. This is how I pass my value.

```
title: {
        text: '<button onclick="Test();"  />'
       }
```

I have tried the following methods but none seemed to work.

```
-onclick="javascript:Test();"

-onclick="javascript:Test;"

-onclick="Test();"

-onclick="this.Test;"

-onclick="this.Test();"
```

I have also tried adding my function outside of my class, inside when it renders and even in the componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate but to no avail.

Comment: you must pass a function that encloses your callback: onlick={()=>Test()}

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work either. It returns everything after ()=> as text...

Comment: I don't understand you you want to call a function from a rendered div. You can't call nothing from a string, I'm quite confused.

Comment: Why does it have to be a string? Please send more code context.

Comment: No problem here is a stackblitz that I have created. Maybe this can help? [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/text-in-object)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making it yourself way too difficult if you only want to replace the graph text with your button. I would define your `test` function in your class:

```
class LineChart extends Component {

test() {
   // Do something
}
// ...
```

and change your jsx to this (To center the button):

```
<div>
  <div
    style={{
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
    <button
      style={{
        margin: 0,
        top: 50,
        left: 50,
      }}
      onClick={this.test}>
      Click Me
    </button>
  </div>

  <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} />
</div>
```

Also set the chart title to an empty string:

```
// ...
title: {
   useHTML: true,
   text: '',
},
// ...
```

This way your button is placed in the middle where your chart title would be and you don't have to call the function via a string.

My fork of your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/text-in-object-sabknh

Comment: I like your solution but it only works for the specific problem. There are scenarios where I would have pop-ups that would need more than one button and they can only be given in the component as a text form.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to have something happen when you click a point in the graph or hover over a point or something else?

Comment: It is not specifically for the graph. There are other libraries that demand the same syntax. A similar example is in Open Layers where it has the pop-ups that accept only text: [link](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html)

Comment: But in the example you linked; triggering the popup and setting the popup data are done with an event listener, not inside the content property.

Comment: Yes, that is true but if in that pop up there is a button in it that opens a modal for example how do I trigger it?